# Unsatisfiable Error when installing py2exe in Anaconda

Tags: python, py2exe

I want to install py2exe using conda install py2exe. However, I keep getting this error:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
> conflict:
>
> - mkl_random
> - py2exe

Could someone please tell me how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?